# Title of a book about about a xenophobic USA re-emerging into the world

Tags: story-identification, novel

Have been trying to locate a science fiction book title I read back in the mid 80’s.

The premise was: The USA withdrew from the outside world and looked inward, severing all ties with other countries. At some point in the “future” they went back into the world to re-discover how the world and other countries had changed/gone away.

Was thinking it was something like the “89th parallel” or something that indicated a “line” on the globe that they would not let anyone pass or they would not pass.

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Parall%C3%A8le-83-Daniel-LAPAUZE/dp/B004APZOHU?

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2329355?

Comment: The parallel in question would probably be the 49th, since that forms much of the U. S.-Canada border.

Comment: Valorum, from what I can understand from [a translated vague summary](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=fr&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.livrenpoche.com%2Fparallele-83-e59693.html&edit-text=), the first one appears to be something else.  The second one you referenced [is a 2017 anthology](https://www.cbc.ca/2017/new-sci-fi-collection-will-alter-canada-s-past-for-the-sake-of-its-future-1.3882494).

Comment: Definitely not the French book. Think the line of demarcation was in the Pacific Ocean. Two hundred years after the USA went into isolation. They one again ventured out into a world that was vastly different. The world had deteriorated and the USA still had its technology. I read it in the 1980’s, and was an older “classic” book then.

Comment: Could it be Beyond Thirty, AKA The Lost Continent, by Edgar Rice Burroughs? Admittedly much older (published in 1915-16 in serial form, in book form 1957) but in the comments you state there it was an older "classic." The rest matches - USA cuts itself of from the rest of the world, with the hero returning to Europe in the year 2137 to find it has returned to barbarism.  In the intervening the once colonized countries of Africa and Asia have conquered much of Europe.